# Create VPN connections in Windows Phone 8.1 programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, vpn

Is there a VPN library available for Windows Phone 8.1 which assists in creating and managing VPN profiles programmatically?

So far I just found out that one can finally setup VPNs manually or by using mobile device management but it seems to me that there is no API one can use programmatically.

**Update:**
There seems to be an API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.vpn.aspx

What is a *Microsoft Account Team representative* and where can I find one?

Answer (score 0):

You should try asking on the [Publishing Windows Store Apps forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/home?forum=windowsstore). They might be able to help get you in contact with the appropriate people.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Windows Phone 8.1 is no longer supported and the VPN features will be published with the release of Windows 10.